# How to make a system monitoring in ubuntu-touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, system-monitor

I want to know a bit of system status in ubuntu-touch for cpu/ memory usage, but I don't know how to get something like the "system monitor" in ubuntu desktop. Is there any tool/ app for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really have an overview of apps, but if you install a terminal, you can use any of the text-based ones available in any Ubuntu system, such as top or htop. They don't have fancy graphics, but they do provide great information.

Comment: Top is available, htop is not.

Comment: Well, technically, it is, although I forgot about the read-only root fs at the time of writing. top is nice enough though.